# Hibernate show_sql exclude package

Tags: hibernate

I'm using show_sql because I like to see what occurs, but I'd like to exclude a class (if necessary) because that runs a query every x minutes and I would rather not have that pop up in my log file.
Anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a solution for this, but it's not using the Hibernate show SQL property.

You can use P6Spy to log your queries. This is a JDBC proxy driver which you set as the driver class in your datasource configuration:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <!-- Only this line changes -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.p6spy.engine.spy.P6SpyDriver</property>
...
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

You can then edit your spy.properties file to exclude a specific table, as described [here](http://octopus.ow2.org/doc/3.2-2/extras/tools/p6spy/other.htm). This should then log all executed SQL (and parameters) and exclude your specified table.

There is more detail on the configuration in [this](http://blog.frankel.ch/debugging-hibernate-generated-sql) article.